# OpenCV error: LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, x86, lnk2019

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.6 and Visual Studio 2008 with Windows8.1 x86.
When I debug my program it signal me 9 errors:

```
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YGHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YGXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __stdcall cv::threshold(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,double,double,int)" (?threshold@cv@@YGNABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@NNH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall cv::cvtColor(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,int,int)" (?cvtColor@cv@@YGXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@HH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall cv::medianBlur(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,int)" (?medianBlur@cv@@YGXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@H@Z) referenced in function _main
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YGXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YGHPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>FYD_control.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall cv::error(class cv::Exception const &)" (?error@cv@@YGXABVException@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: int & __thiscall cv::Mat::at<int>(int,int)" (??$at@H@Mat@cv@@QAEAAHHH@Z)
1>C:\Users\___________________________\Debug\FYD2_Control.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\_________________\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>FYD2_Control - 9 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I've analized everything and I've noticed that while in this errors I have

```
(?waitKey@cv@@YGHH@Z)
(?imshow@cv@@YGXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z)
(?threshold@cv@@YGNABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@NNH@Z)
(?cvtColor@cv@@YGXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@HH@Z)
(?medianBlur@cv@@YGXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@H@Z)
(?fastFree@cv@@YGXPAX@Z)
(?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YGHPAHH@Z)
(?error@cv@@YGXABVException@1@@Z)
```

if I analize the .lib there is the same, but with A instead the first G

```
(?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z)
(?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z)
(?threshold@cv@@YANABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@NNH@Z)
(?cvtColor@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@HH@Z)
(?medianBlur@cv@@YAXABV_InputArray@1@ABV_OutputArray@1@H@Z)
(?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z)
(?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPAHH@Z)
(?error@cv@@YAXABVException@1@@Z)
```

Substituting the A with G in the .lib I solve this problem, but later it gives me an other error

```
The procedure entry point ?fastFree@cv@@YGXPAX@Z could not be
located in the dynamic link library
```

How can I solve this?

Sorry for my english and thank's to anyone will answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with linking. replacing A with G in your library wont help. Make sure that you have added all libraries in additional dependencies. Below are the most necessary lib files make sure you have included it.

```
highgui210d.lib 
cxcore210d.lib 
cv210d.lib
```

Once you have done this if u still get error then go to lib folder of opencv  (C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib) and add all the lib files to additional dependencies (right click on your project select properties->configuration properties->linker->input then on right pane locate additional dependencies then add all lib file names) of your project.